# Phaser problem: loading images imported from files as base64 data

Tags: base64, phaser-framework

I have trouble loading image(s) as Base64 data. In the following code (partially borrowed from [here](https://supernapie.com/blog/loading-assets-as-data-uri-in-phaser-3/)), the 'loading' function `this.textures.addBase64` is used:

```
import bgSrc from '../assets/img/back.png';
...

create()  {
  this.numToLoad = 1;
  this.textures.on('addtexture', () => {
    console.log('another image loaded')
    this.numToLoad--;
    if (this.numToLoad < 1) this.createNext();
  })

  this.textures.addBase64('background', bgSrc);
  ...
}

createNext() {
  //...use the images
}
```

However, the 'addtexture' event never fires. And the image, loaded this way, never loads, no matter how long I wait.
But everything goes fine if I use direct Base64 code, like `const bgSrc = 'data:image/png;base64, blablablah'` instead of `import bgSrc from '../assets/img/back.png'`. So the problem is in importing the image.

I use phaser 3 webpack in this project. plus [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader). Maybe the url-loader is incorrectly set up? I am not sure if the url-loader is even needed for performing `npm run start`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was indeed an incorrect setup of the url-loader. (I used one more plugin in the webpack, and they didn't work well together.)

So, the code above is OK after all.